# Parameterless constructor error with autofac in web api 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-web-api2, autofac, neo4jclient

I am using Autofac as IOC and here is my structure:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AdTudent.Repo
{
    public interface IRepository
    {
        IAdvertisementRepository Advertisements { get; set; }
        IProfileRepository Profiles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My repositories class is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AdTudent.Repo
{
    public class Repositories : IRepository
    {
        public Repositories(IAdvertisementRepository advertisementRepository,
                            IProfileRepository profileRepository)
        {
            Advertisements = advertisementRepository;
            Profiles = profileRepository;
        }
        public IAdvertisementRepository Advertisements { get; set; }
        public IProfileRepository Profiles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And my startup class is:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
         var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<Repositories>().As<IRepository>();
        builder.Register<IGraphClient>(context =>
        {
            var graphClient = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"));
            graphClient.Connect();
            return graphClient;
        }).SingleInstance();
        // STANDARD WEB API SETUP:

        // Get your HttpConfiguration. In OWIN, you'll create one
        // rather than using GlobalConfiguration.
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        // Register your Web API controllers.
        //builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        // Run other optional steps, like registering filters,
        // per-controller-type services, etc., then set the dependency resolver
        // to be Autofac.
       
        var container = builder.Build();
        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        // OWIN WEB API SETUP:

        // Register the Autofac middleware FIRST, then the Autofac Web API middleware,
        // and finally the standard Web API middleware.
        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
        app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
        app.UseWebApi(config);

        ConfigureAuth(app);
    }
}
```

and here is my account controller:

```
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    private  IRepository _repository;
    private const string LocalLoginProvider = "Local";
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    private IGraphClient _graphClient;
   

    public ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> AccessTokenFormat { get; private set; }       

    public AccountController(IRepository repository, IGraphClient graphClient,
         ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket> accessTokenFormat)
    {
        
        AccessTokenFormat = accessTokenFormat;
        _repository = repository;
        _graphClient = graphClient;

    }
}
```

but I always this problem

```
"Message": "An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage": "An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'AccountController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.",
"ExceptionType": "System.InvalidOperationException",
"StackTrace": "   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerDescriptor.CreateController(HttpRequestMessage request)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
```

I searched on the internet but I couldn't find anything that can help can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 7):

Per the [WebApi OWIN documentation](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#owin-integration):

> A common error in OWIN integration is use of the `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration`. **In OWIN you create the configuration from scratch.** You should not reference `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration` anywhere when using the OWIN integration.

It looks like you have a couple of issues:

1. The `HttpConfiguration` needs to be newed up when using OWIN.
2. You are missing the `UseAutofacWebApi` virtual method call.

You also need the [Autofac WebApi OWIN package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Autofac.WebApi2.Owin/) as per the docs.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // STANDARD WEB API SETUP:

        // Get your HttpConfiguration. In OWIN, you'll create one
        // rather than using GlobalConfiguration.
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        // Register your Web API controllers.
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        // Run other optional steps, like registering filters,
        // per-controller-type services, etc., then set the dependency resolver
        // to be Autofac.
        var container = builder.Build();
        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        // OWIN WEB API SETUP:

        // Register the Autofac middleware FIRST, then the Autofac Web API middleware,
        // and finally the standard Web API middleware.
        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
        app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't need for MVC controllers I just need web api controller as I mentioned above, do you have any idea?

Comment: You are also not registering your global filters in the correct order. You need to call `builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);` before you call `builder.Build();`. See my example above.

Comment: I edited the code as you said but the same result as before, do you have any further idea?

Comment: Thanks alot  for your help I have the same error bud in stacktrace I don't have any problem in autofac it seems that problem is in other part,can you help me one more time? I also installed Autofac Web Api Owin package

Answer (score 1):

Check your Global.asax.cs. You should remove this line if you have it:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
```

You can move this to Startup.cs Configuration like this:

```
WebApiConfig.Register(config);
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told Autofac how to create an `ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>` instance.

Add this in your startup class before your call `builder.Build()`.

```
builder.RegisterType<ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>>().As<TicketDataFormat>();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but the problem is not the thing that you mention I tried that but not working

Comment: Try posting a complete sample that one can actually run. Otherwise its anyone's guess.